"Pas besoin de verbe" or "Non pas besoin de verbe" in a bullet point
I'm authoring a slideshow in French. I want to express something like "there is no need for a verb" in a bullet point. In English, I'd write "No verb needed" for the sake of brevity.
What is the correct way to state that in French? "Pas besoin de verbe" seems odd. Even though it is the way that you'd say it in day-to-day life, in an official document it seems grammatically lacking. Should I rather write "Non pas besoin de verbe", the same way I'd write "J'ai soif, et non pas faim"?
The sentence "Il n'y a pas besoin de verbe" seems to be an overkill in a slide bullet point.
Thanks for your insights.

Pas besoin de verbe is just fine in a slide show, including an "official" one.
*Non pas besoin de verbe doesn't work. That might be possible with a comma: "Non, pas besoin de verbe" but that would be a reply to "Besoin de verbe ?"
Alternatives could be:
Verbe optionnel
Verbe non requis
and the already mentioned:
Verbe facultatif
Aucun verbe requis
You might also add some opinion like with:
Verbe superflu
Verbe inutile
